# A getter added to an object with Object.assign() sees the wrong value for a closure variable?

Tags: javascript, closures, getter-setter

this works (final result is 1)

```
function jkl() {

    let callCount = 0

    let replacer = {
        get callCount() { return callCount },
    }

    Object.assign(replacer, {
        count() { ++callCount },
    })

    return replacer
}

j = jkl()
j.count()
j.callCount // 1
```

but this doesn't (final result is 0)

```
function abc() {

    let callCount = 0

    let replacer = {
        count() { ++callCount },
    }

    Object.assign(replacer, {
        get callCount() { return callCount },
    })

    return replacer
}

a = abc()
a.count()
a.callCount // 0
```

Any idea why the 2nd one doesn't work as intended?

(i've tried some other ways of doing the same thing and they're all here https://tonicdev.com/nfc/assign-get-closure )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this: (`assign` does not work for this)

[`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
"use strict"

function abc() {

    let callCount = 0

    let replacer = {
        count() { ++callCount },
    }

    Object.defineProperty(replacer, 'callCount', {
        get: function() { return callCount }
    })

    return replacer
}

var a = abc()
a.count()
console.log(a.callCount) // 1
```

Comment: yeah i know i can use Object.defineProperty(). My question is why assign() works for the regular object method but not for the getter... (works as in the method executes in the expected closure)

Comment: `Object.assign` creates a new Object so you need `replacer = Object.assign(replacer, ...)` first auf all. Also it wont work with assign because it will create a local variable "callCount" bound to  this (the new Object created by assing), not to the "callCount" of the function-scope!

Comment: thanks! i didn't realise Object.assign() turns getters into whatever value that getter returns when Object.assign() runs, in case anyone else runs into this the answer is here https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-working-with-accessor-properties

Comment: though i do think Object.assign modifies the target object, when i run this in Safari's console `a = { b: 1 }; Object.assign(a, { c: 3 }); console.log(a)` i get `{b: 1, c: 3}` as output

Comment: @NunoCampos you are right! I overlooked that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign